# Decomposing a point in a polytope with a randomly sampled set of its extremal points

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, polyhedra, convex-geometry, polytopes

(I'm not sure how to title this as I have several related questions, so I did it with the most interesting one)

Let $P$ be a convex polytope. By Carathéodory's theorem, we can always decompose an $x \in P$ as a convex combination of at most $d+1$ other points in $P$: $x = \sum_{i = 0}^d \alpha_i u_i$, with $\sum_i \alpha_i = 1$ and $\alpha_i \geq 0$, where the $\{u_i\}_i$ are points in $P$.

**Q1:** Given an $x \in P$, what are good algorithms for finding its minimal decomposition, i.e., the one using at most $d+1$ extremal points?

Let $V = \{v_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$ be the set of all $n$ extremal points of a polytope $P = \text{conv}\,(V) \in \mathcal{R}^d$.

**Q2:** Can I also decompose $x$ with at most $d+1$ of the *extremal* points of $P$?

For the last question, suppose I have a $d$-dimensional polytope with $n \gg d$ extremal points. I now want to try to find a description of an $y$, *which may not be in $P$*, in terms of extremal points of $P$. This could be done with linear programming, given I had all of the $\{v_i\}_{i=0}^{n-1}$ (and it would tell me with certainty whether $y \in P$ or not).

Consider, though, that I cannot store all of the $n$ extremal points, but I can sample any reasonable $k$ of them. With those $k$, I want to answer whether $y \in P$ or not. I am also allowed to run the program with $r$ different random samples.

**Q3:** Are there any theorems of algorithms which would guide me on how big the number $k$ of sampled extremal points should be, and how many $r$ runs should I have, for reaching a certain bound on the probability that $y \in P$ or not?

This last one may be too specific a question, so I don't expect a fully developed answer or reference. If all you can think of is a hint on where to look for something similar to this, it'd already be very welcome.

Comment: On Q3: That depends on the polytope. If you take a polytope in $\mathbb R^d$ and split one of its corners (so it has two corners right next to each other where the other had one), any selection of $d+1$ corners that includes both of the new corners spans volume $0$ whereas all other selections still span the same volume; so the average volume spanned (and thus the probability that a point in $P$ is in the span) has decreased.

Comment: That's a good observation. Probably there won't be a general method, then, and I'll have to analyze it instance-wise. Also, I found an answer to Q2, and possibly to Q1. I'll post them soon.